# How can I create a non-square BufferedImage from a non-square image file?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm trying to create a BufferedImage from an arbitrary image file and then center that image in the background of a JPanel.  I don't have any problems with square images, but I can't figure out how to handle non-square images.

Some debugging indicates that the (immediate) problem is that when I use ImageIO to create a BufferedImage from a rectangular input file, say one that's 256x128, BufferedImage.getHeight() returns 256 rather than 128.

Here's a snippet approximating my code:

```
class ExtendedPanel extends JPanel {

    static final int WIDTH = 400;
    static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    BufferedImage image;

    public ExtendedPanel(File f) {
       super();
       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
       image = ImageIO.read(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int x = (WIDTH - image.getWidth())/2;
        int y = (HEIGHT - image.getHeight())/2;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2d)g;
        g2d.drawRenderedImage(image,AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y));
    }

}
```

As I said, this is fine for square image files.  But with rectangular images that are wider than they are tall, the image is displayed higher than it should be.  I haven't tried it yet with images taller than they are wide but I'm afraid that it that case the image would be displayed too far to the left.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more a problem of (understanding) the right calculation.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2d)g;

    // How to scale the image:
    double xscale = ((double)WIDTH) / image.getWidth();
    double yscale = ((double)HEIGHT) / image.getHeight());

    // When scaling proportionally:
    double scale = Math.min(xscale, yscale); // max for covering entire panel.
    xscale = scale;
    yscale = scale;

    double w = scalex * image.getWidth();
    double h = scaley * image.getHeight();
    double x = (getWidth() - w) / 2;
    double y = (getHeight() - h) / 2;
    g.drawImage(img, (int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h, Color.BLACK, null);
    //g2d.translate(x, y);
    //g2d.scale(xscale, yscale);
    //g2d.draw...;
}
```

Using the simple (scaling) version of `drawImage` what is needed is entirely clear.

To be considered is proportionally scaling, filling entirely (loss of image part) or upto maximal size (seeing background).

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't considered the issue of scaling yet, as all the test images I have to work with are 256x256 or smaller.  As it turns out, my problem was a typo in a wrapper class I'd written for BufferedImage to hold positional and rotational information along with the image itself, but I have bookmarked your answer for future reference.